# Merging bordering curve objects together

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry

I'm trying to make a 3D map from an SVG file using US counties and states. I've imported an SVG of all the counties into blender and have them as separate objects in the scene like so:

[image]

What I'm trying to do next is merge counties by state, but when I join the curve objects together they start to look wrong. The nice 3D surface gets distorted and doesn't appear in all the areas that it did before merging.

I also want to merge the inner borders together so the new object only has points for the outline of the complete state, but trying to Merge by Distance on the points doesn't have any effect.

Object after merging:
[image]

I've also tried another approach where I convert the curves into meshes, but this introduces a new problem where the surface of the mesh is triangulated, and it's hard to sort out which edges are on the border and which are inside. If there's a way to convert to mesh and keep everything as n-gons (the same way they look when rendered as curve objects in the first pic), then that could work as well.

Comment: Curves can't have more than 2 adjacent control points, so I guess it's your problem here? You can't merge these curves and keep the frontiere between the states, you need to remove. You can convert to mesh, but you may need to create some inner edges if you want the shape to be filled